# Is it possible to remove a database server from a cluster resource, but keep it running on the node

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I was wondering if anyone knew whether it was possible to delete the cluster resource, but keep all of the disks and sql instance running on the node instead? So if I was to delete the cluster resource, would the instance continue running on the node?

Comment: That node won't have any of your databases online or available unless it's the active node. What would be the point?

Comment: Is this question driven by some other administrative activity, or is it hypothetical? If it's the former, I would suggest editing the question to let us know what you're trying to do.

Comment: What server OS, what SQL Server version? And are you trying to do this in uptime, or fix a broken cluster resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The instance is configured to use cluster resources and as such if the cluster is removed the instance will not function correctly.

If you like to play with fire in an experimental-not-in-production-learn-by-trial-and-error way, you can do the opposite of [How to move SQL Server from Standalone to Cluster environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/blakhani/how-to-move-sql-server-from-standalone-to-cluster-environment).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about your cluster I am going to say NO. Since SQL Server was installed as part of the cluster, removing the resource is going remove the clusters knowledge of the SQL Server instance. There will be nothing for users to connect to because an entry path does not exist. Everything will still be there, but waiting in stasis until control is established. The drives and database instance will probably remain on the current node because there will be no voting mechanism to tell them to switch.

What are you trying to accomplish?